# Can retaining a previous binary lead to failed app reviews?

Tags: android, google-play, review, android-auto

Say you have an existing app on the play store that's *not* enabled for Android Auto (no Android Auto metadata in the manifest, etc.), and you want to release a new version that is.  When deploying the new release, Google Play warns you that the new build is compatible with fewer devices than the original.

So you decide to retain the previous binary as part of the new release.  As in, the new release includes two APK's, one which includes Android Auto support and one which does not.

Could this configuration lead to the release being rejected when Google reviews it for Android Auto, or is their review process smart enough to ignore the APK that's not flagged as supporting Auto?

Specifically, I'm wondering is this kind of setup might lead to a vague/nonspecific rejection reason, like:

> Your app does not perform all functions properly or as expected from a
>   user perspective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

- If you released the app with the older binaries, I am assuming that the Android auto flag is not active here (as informed), then the auto team will not review it, as the review process is not triggered.
- If you released the app with auto functionality, then it will trigger the review process. 
  You can find more information on the review process
  https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/distribute-auto.html

You should always make sure that your app meets all the Auto app quality guidelines, and upload it to the Google Play console and publish the app as usual.

Before making your app available to the users, Google Play will submit your app for review against the Auto app quality, and will notify you of the result. Once approved the app will be available to the users.